# How can I get the name of the field from an expression?

Tags: c#

I have an expression, passed to a function, that looks something like this:

```
x=>x.SomeField
```

I want somehow to get to the name of this field, the "SomeField", to be accessible for me as a string. 
I realize that it's possible to call myExpression.ToString(), and then parse the string, but I want a more solid, faster approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the property name used in a Lambda Expression in .NET 3.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269518/get-the-property-name-used-in-a-lambda-expression-in-net-3-5)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public string GetMemberName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
{
    var memberExpr = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpr == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Expression body must be a MemberExpression");
    return memberExpr.Member.Name;
}

...

MyClass x = /* whatever */;
string name = GetMemberName(() => x.Something); // returns "Something"
```

Comment: Thats shorter - if he only has to deal with MemberExpressions.

Comment: If you want to statically define the propertyName:static readonly string SomethingProperty = GetMemberName(() => default(MyClass).Something); Also, you might want to disable warning 1720 so that the null use is not checked

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement a expression tree visitor

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521(VS.90).aspx

You put your eval code in the MemberAccessExpression visit

Comment: Yes - that's true. But mostly everything starts with an simple task :-)

Comment: thank you for this link too. Will keep it in mind when something bigger comes up.

Answer (score 0):

I've used some of the helpers available in the [ncommon](http://github.com/riteshrao/ncommon/) framework to accomplish this. Specifically, you'd be interested in the classes in the [Expressions namespace](http://github.com/riteshrao/ncommon/tree/v1.1/NCommon/src/Expressions/)