# Getting the results of distinct( IEqualityComparer comparer)

Tags: c#, linq

As a LINQ-beginner I wonder why nobody mentioned in [Implementing IEqualityComparer<T> for comparing arbitrary properties of any class (including anonymous)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345854/implementing-iequalitycomparert-for-comparing-arbitrary-properties-of-any-clas) that the query actually has to be carried out to get the results. In other words, just calling
`IEnumerable<Person> people = ... ; // some database call here
var distinctPeople = people.Distinct(new PropertyComparer<Person>("FirstName"));`
will not trigger the execution of the specific `Equals(Tx, Ty)` and `GetHashCode(T obj)` methods in the PropertyComparer.

The message "Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable" (in the Debugger) gave me the hint. Now, could I proceed with something like `foreach (var dp in distinctPeople)` to get the results?

Comment: What is the question? How to use Distinct on IEnumerable?

Comment: And as for why no-one happened to mention it - pretty much everything in LINQ is lazy. There's nothing special about `Distinct` here. There's no point in mentioning that in every single answer to every single question about LINQ.

Comment: Feels opinion based/too broad to me. This may be better question to meta - how deep one is expected to explain particular solution. I.e. whether targeting complete beginners is a goal or one should stop explanation on current level of calls.

Comment: @JordyvanEijk: I was working on the `equals` and `GetHashCode` methods and did not understand why they were not called when calling `people.Distinct(new comparer("Firstname"))`. Now things got clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing at all to do with the `IEqualityComparer`.  It is entirely based on the method you're providing it to, in this case, `Distinct`.  `Distinct`, along with all of the LINQ methods that return an `IEnumerable`, defer execution as much as possible, only performing the work that they need to compute the results when they actually need to do so.