# C# Reflection - Get PropertyInfo without a string

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a property in `Myclass`:

```
public class MyClass{    
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
}
```

How can I get the `PropertyInfo` (using `GetProperty("FirstName")`) without a string?

Today I use this:

```
PropertyInfo propertyTitleNews = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("FirstName");
```

Is there a way for use like this:

```
PropertyInfo propertyTitleNews = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty(MyClass.FirstName);
```

?

Comment: Seems like if you had access to the properties of the class like that you wouldn't need reflection to begin with.  If this is .NET 4 or later, have you tried using the Dynamic keyword?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. [look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17049349/1082327).

Comment: I agree with Locke. It doesn't make much sense. You usually use reflection when you the only way to create a property is from string.

Comment: @Szymon No, in general it does make sense as `PropertyInfo` has more information than only property's type and its value.

Comment: Beware of all answers that deals with member expressions. There is a tripping corner case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658669/lambda-expression-not-returning-expected-memberinfo ! Not a very safe thing to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [here](http://handcraftsman.wordpress.com/2008/11/11/how-to-get-c-property-names-without-magic-strings/). The idea is to use Expression Trees.

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T, TReturn>(Expression<Func<T, TReturn>> expression)
{
    MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    return body.Member.Name;
}
```

And then use it like:

```
var name = GetPropertyName<MyClass, string>(c => c.FirstName);
```

A bit cleaner solution would be if one would not required to specify so much generic parameters. And it is possible via moving `MyClass` generic param to util class:

```
public static class TypeMember<T>
{
    public static string GetPropertyName<TReturn>(Expression<Func<T, TReturn>> expression)
    {
        MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
        return body.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

Then usage will be cleaner:

```
var name = TypeMember<MyClass>.GetPropertyName(c => c.FirstName);
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without the overhead of lambda?

Comment: @rolls what overhead do you mean? The lambda isn't _executed_ ever, so it is just a data passed by the compiler. The lambda doesn't capture any locals either, so there are no additional allocations as well.

Comment: Good point. I didn't think about it in that level of detail, it is not much different to passing in an object/struct really.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility, beside [Ivan Danilov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19883689/2642204), is to provide an extension method:

```
public static class PropertyInfoExtensions
{
    public static string GetPropertyName<TType, TReturnType>(
        this TType @this,
        Expression<Func<TType, TReturnType>> propertyId)
    {
        return ((MemberExpression)propertyId.Body).Member.Name;
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
MyClass c;
PropertyInfo propertyTitleNews = c.GetPropertyName(x => x.FirstName);
```

The drawback is that you need an instance, but an advantage is that you don't need to supply generic arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that

```
var property = ExpressionExtensions.GetProperty<MyClass>(o => o.FirstName);
```

With this helper :

```
public static PropertyInfo GetProperty<T>(Expression<Func<T, Object>> expression)
{
     MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
     return typeof(T).GetProperty(body.Member.Name);
}
```