# What is the difference between Member Expressions and an Expression Tree Generated by a Lambda?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

This title might not actually make sense, because these things might be entirely different. First, let me explain why I'm trying to learn about this:

I'm currently trying to write a unit test for a method that touches a lot of properties. Due to that, I'd prefer to write a test that takes in a list of property names as its member data and that will not start randomly failing if someone goes and changes the name of the property. At first, I started with string reflection, but I knew that's a bad idea as it fails that second caveat.

That led me to the following thread and the following code: [C# Reflection - Get PropertyInfo without a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883645/c-sharp-reflection-get-propertyinfo-without-a-string)

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T, TReturn>(Expression<Func<T, TReturn>> expression)
{
    MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    return body.Member.Name;
}
```

This works well with GetValue(), but now I'm trying to understand it. I think I understand how the Expression class basically takes apart the expression lambda and builds a class from it, but I'm trying to understand what the MemberExpression really is and what the difference is with it that allows me to access the name of a class property. I apologize if I'm way off track here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a `MemberExpression` is an expression that allows you to access the members of an instance, be a field or a property. It stores the information needed to retrieve that member, such as the host class, member name and type.

Here is the content of FieldMember and PropertyMember : 
*Screenshot generated from LINQPad `.Dump()`.*

[image]
[image]

Source :

```
void Main()
{
    GetPropertyName<Foo, string>(f => f.Bar);
    GetPropertyName<Foo, string>(f => f.bar);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static string GetPropertyName<T, TReturn>(Expression<Func<T, TReturn>> expression)
{
    expression.Dump();

    MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    return body.Member.Name;
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public string bar;
}
```

Comment: For those wodering, those images and the `.Dump()` function are from the program [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) (I think, they look exactly like screens from LINQPad)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, they are.

Comment: Could you also add a screenshot of .Dump() on body?

Comment: The `.Body` is included in both of the screenshots. Check the block that has `FieldExpression` and `PropertyExpression` as header.

Comment: Oh, I meant MemberExpression body. But if it's the same exact info, nevermind. Thanks!

Comment: `(MemberExpression)expression.Body` <- means cast the expression's `.Body` into a `MemberExpression`

Comment: Right, I understand it's casting it. I just thought it would help clarify to see the structure of the MemberExpression in comparison to the .Body that is being cast into the new object.

Comment: It is the same. MemberExpression is just the base type of `.Body`(for these 2 expressions specifically). Anyways here is the screenshot of them : http://i.imgur.com/IZUr5o8.png