# how to search an obj for a variable, given variable name as string

Tags: c#, linq, factual

I have a large list of objects, the object contains things like string name, string address, string city.

I want to create a findEqualsMatch method like this.. where it takes in a string called varName, and then searches the variable of the object which varName is called.

that way if i do data.FindEquals("name", "tom") it searches the objects "name" property to be equal to tom, at the same time you can write "address" and it will search the address property.

```
public List<Datum> FindEquals(String varName, String value)
            {
                List<Datum> results = new List<Datum>();
                foreach (Datum result in data)
                {
                    //should search for address variable
                    // instead of if(result.Address == value)

                    if (result.varName == value)
                        results.Add(result);

                }

                return results;
            }

List<Datum> newResults = data.FindEquals("address", "123 street");
```

the whole purpose is to query a set of factual API results and return a set that is searched on by any variable type you insert into the function.

Comment: What are you searching for? value or varName?

Comment: I am searching for value, of the variable from varName inside of an object... does that clearify?

that way if i do data.FindEquals("name", "tom") it searches the objects "name" property to be equal to tom, at the same time you can write "address" and it will search the address property.

Comment: You'd have to use reflection (see below), or better/faster/type-safe is to replace `String varName` by a matcher delegate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx). Starting from [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp) your sample will look like:

```
public List<Datum> FindEquals(String varName, String value)
        {
            List<Datum> results = new List<Datum>();
            var propertyInfo = (typeof Datum).GetProperty(varName);
            foreach (Datum result in data)
            {
                String varValue = (string)propertyInfo.GetValue(result, null);
                if (varValue == value)
                    results.Add(result);
            }
            return results;
        }
```

Alternatively you can use `Func<string, Datum>` as field accessor arguments or corresponding Expression tree similar to LINQ-to-SQL (i.e. [Get the property name used in a Lambda Expression in .NET 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269518/get-the-property-name-used-in-a-lambda-expression-in-net-3-5))

Comment: genius thanks, fixes my issue with needing to access varName as well, could not do that with previous example.

Comment: No problem. You should mark my question question as answer if it helped.

Comment: I've added alternative approach from my (deleted) answer as I marked whole question as duplicate of reflection call. Feel free to revert/improve.