# call PropertyChange with public member, not string C#

Tags: c#, .net

I've looked around a bit online and wasn't able to easily find a solution to what i was looking for. It may be in part to me not being sure the terminology to search for.

I wanted to know is there a way to call the PropertyChanged event using the property member name like so...

```
    private string height;
    public string Height
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            Set(ref height, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged( ()=> Name);
        }
    }
```

rather than using the actual string which can be seen here..

```
    private string height;
    public string Height
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            Set(ref height, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
```

**Raise Event**

```
protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
     PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

I've attempted a solution to this, but wasn't able to come to a conclusion. I know there are methods out there somewhere and im sure there are more modern ways to do this. Its 2016!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you appear to be using C# 6, you can use the `nameof` operator, which resolves the name of the referenced property at compile time, passing a string to your method.

```
RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
```

If you need to use an earlier C# compiler, you can resolve the name of the property through a lambda expression; this is what Entity Framework does for its `Include` operator. You can define a `GetPropertyName` utility method (see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3269604/1149773)), then call it like so:

```
RaisePropertyChanged(GetPropertyName(() => Name));
```

Comment: How would you do it in C#4 and C#5.

keep the above answer to please

Comment: Just out of curiosity what makes it appear to be C# 6?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: There are multiple ways to implement `GetPropertyName`; the one I referenced doesn't have a parameter. But your point is valid for expressions passed to `Include`.

Comment: @JokerMartini: The `?.` null-conditional operator (in `PropertyChanged?.Invoke`) was also introduced in C# 6.